# Why are Pandas and Seaborn producing different KDE Plot for same data?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, kde-plasma

I am trying to have a look at the distribution of a variable with the following values..

```
+-------+-------+
| Value | Count |
+-------+-------+
| 0.0   |   355 |
| 1.0   |   935 |
| 2.0   |     1 |
| 3.0   |     2 |
| 4.0   |     1 |
+-------+-------+
```

The table continues with values up to 1000 but **very sparse** (total observations = 1622, almost all the observations fall in 0 or 1)

So when plotting I did:

`sns.distplot(kde=True, a = df.loc[(df.class == 1)].variable_of_interest)`

Which produces the following red distribution

[image: KDE Plot with seaborn]

Seaborn does not capture the initial concentration of values, but shows more "sensibility" to the rest of the values

Then I remembered `pd.DataFrame.plot.kde()` , so I gave it a try and it produces this plot that captures the concentration

`df.loc[(df.class== 1)].variable_of_interest.plot.kde()`

[image: Pandas KDE Distribution]

*Important note: For those who might notice a difference in the X-axis, I did try the seaborn with xlims(-500, 1000) yet the plot remains exactly the same*

**Do you know why do they generate such different plots? 
Does it have to do with how they process data, or I am doing something wrong?**

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's going wrong is that the [kde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) is primarily  meant for continuous data, while you seem to be working with discrete data. An important parameter is the `bandwidth`: the smaller it is, the closer the curve fits to the data, the wider the better to indicate a general form.

It seems seaborn and pandas are using a different approach here to estimate a "good" bandwidth. With [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html#kernel-density-estimation) you could set a fixed bandwidth `sns.kdeplot(..., bw=0.5)` or so.  Or [`seaborn.distplot(..., kde=True, kde_kws={'bw': 0.5})`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html). With [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.kde.html) `df.plot.kde(bw_method=0.5, ...)`. Note that the "perfect" bandwidth doesn't exist, it depends on the data, the number of samples and about what you already know about the underlying distribution. The default seaborn and pandas choose is just a rule of thumb, that might be useful or not for your data. Future versions will probably use different rules of thumb.

The following image shows how different bandwidths influences a kdeplot:

[image: kdeplot different bandwidths]

Comment: Thanks @JohanC, what you point out is true about continuous and discrete variables, yet I was expecting to get "a sense" of the distribution in a graphical manner, despite not being correct I thought it could give me a hint. 
I have played a little bit with those parameters and I do get similar shapes, yet I still could not find the exact parametrization to get equal plot (not that I need it, but just out of curiosity) 

Again thanks!

Comment: Usually, [Scott's rule](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) is used to estimate a bandwidth. Which would be `n**(-1./(d+4))` with `n` the number of data points (1622?), and `d` the dimension (1), so about `0.228`.  Seaborn uses a slight [variation to Scott's rule](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/_modules/statsmodels/nonparametric/kde.html#KDEUnivariate) *`"scott" - 1.059 * A * nobs ** (-1/5.)`, where `A` is `min(std(X),IQR/1.34)`* which doesn't work out well in this case.